# Recursive wget eventually starts failing with "Unable to resolve host" / "Temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: wget

When recursively `wget`-ting a fairly large site, after downloading 18 MB or so, `wget` starts complaining "Unable to resolve host" and/or "Temporary failure in name resolution", even though I can look up the host just fine with `host` or `dig`.

On the advice of various fora, I tried:

1. commenting out the `hosts` line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`
2. replacing potentially dodgy nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` with Google's `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`
3. explicitly adding the name to `/etc/hosts`

It doesn't seem to matter whether or not I set `--no-dns-cache` in the `wget` command line; the same thing happens.

I can't tell if `wget` is eventually going to finish, or if it's going to stay stuck in this state. It'd be nice if it finished, since I need it to `--convert-links`.

I'm running `wget` 1.11 (compiled from source, because 1.12 and later have [broken](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?31781)  the behavior of `--no-clobber` with `--convert-links`, at least for my purposes) on a Linux Mint 14 system.

What causes this? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: You may run wget through strace in order to see what really happens. With a bit luck this can be seen in the output: `strace -tt -f -o wget.strace wget ...` That file is going to be big (few 100 K at least). Interesting is just the last part before the crash.

Comment: Some servers don't like being hammered, and accept only so many requests from a particular IP address. That is what the `--limit-rate=` and `--wait=` flags are for.

Comment: A server blocking requests would not exhibit as a host lookup failure. How many file descriptors does the wget process have when the errors start occurring? `lsof -p $(pgrep wget)`

Comment: @mindthemonkey I think you might be on to something -- I left it to complete overnight, and came back to find the conversion process complaining "Too many open files".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the true fix will most likely be using the latest version of `wget` as the issues have probably been fixed there. 1.11 is about 5 years old. There is a [1.11.4](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.11.4.tar.gz) too if you happen to be using the original 1.11.

Alternatively (and this is horrible.. and might not work depending on what is triggering the file descriptor usage):

- Increase the [file ulimit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645/1318694) for the user running wget.
- Work out a way to resume your `wget` nicely.
- Monitor the fd usage via `lsof` or a simple `ls /proc/$pid/fd`
- Restart your `wget` when it gets close to your `ulimit` of files.

Otherwise you would need to trace what is leaking the fd's in `wget` and patch it. There may be known file descriptor leak patches you could backport to 1.11. I can't seem to find a public version control for the `wget` source though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw this in 1.13 before I noticed the `noclobber` problem, but I suspect you're right about the file descriptors. And yes, while you can get a tarball of the release source, GNU is unfortunately quite a lot behind the times in terms of public source control.

Comment: @mindthemonkey: `curl` and Perl's `WWW::Mechanize` could be an alternative as well.

Comment: @0xC0000022L `curl` would take a whole lot of scripting though as it doesn't have the recursive/mirror features. I've not used `WWW::Mechanize`, but it looks the same, a module you could write a recursive perl getter with?

Comment: @mindthemonkey: yes, you do the parsing yourself to resolve links, that's correct.